# "this" always on top when visible

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game in As3.

I've got a child named "batiments". It is called in my Engine class at the begining of the game, like that :

```
    batiments = new Batiments(stage);
    addChild(batiments);
    batiments.visible = false;
```

So, when the player clicks on a button on the stage, it's calling this function :

```
private function showBatiments():void{
        Engine.batiments.visible = true;
    }
```

BUT, during my game, other childs are being called randomly every 2 minutes. Like that :

```
public function apparitionDechet(event : TimerEvent):void{
    var mc:DisplayObject = new _classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * _classes.length)]();
    _movieClips.push(mc);
    stageRef.addChild(mc);
    mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removePoubelle, false, 0, true);
```

**Problem : When the function "`showBatiments`" is called and batiments is visible, the mc child are on top of it. Is it possible to put in my code something to say batiments should always be on top of everything ?**

I've got an `Engine.as` class (where batiments is added). 
I've got a `Batiments.as` class (so batiments has is own class). 
I've got a `Dechet.as` class (where the mc child are added randomly).

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `addChildAt(target, index)` like so,

```
stageRef.addChildAt(mc, 0);
stageRef.addChildAt(batiments, 1);
```

Provided that `stageRef` is available in Engine class.

For more info see [addChildAt](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChildAt%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to split it into 2 layers.
One for your 'Batiments' over top of the other which holds the 'mc's